# kubernates onpremesis ingress nginx bad gateway

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vps, kubernetes

Hello I am quite new to kubernates
So I have installed kubernates on an Ubuntu DPS
then I have also added ngnx-ingress-controller `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.35.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml`

my deployment is a react app that runs nginx:1.15 on port 80

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: clientweb-dep
  labels:
    appcluster: ethernial
    app: clientweb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: clientweb
  template:
    metadata:
      name: clientweb-template
      labels:
        appcluster: ethernial
        app: clientweb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: clientweb
        image: ethernial.azurecr.io/clientweb
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 300Mi
        env:
        - name: APPNAME
          value: clientweb
        - name: CONTAINERNAME
          value: clientweb
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http-port
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: acr-secret
```

my service:

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    appcluster: ethernial
    app: clientweb
  name: clientweb-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: http
  selector:
    app: clientweb
  type: ClusterIP
```

and this is the ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1

kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: clientweb-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: clientweb-service
              servicePort: 80
```

But when I got to the ip or domain URL I get 502 Bad Gateway so what am I missing?

kubectl get all -A -o wide

```
master-node:/tmp/deps# kubectl get all -A -o wide
NAMESPACE       NAME                                            READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default         pod/clientweb-dep-5d58cfb88f-f4ntq              1/1     Running     0          21d     10.244.0.21     master-node   <none>           <none>
default         pod/portalapi-dep-c8845948b-7sf2w               1/1     Running     0          23d     10.244.0.20     master-node   <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx   pod/ingress-nginx-admission-create-xnxrm        0/1     Completed   0          2d23h   10.244.0.22     master-node   <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx   pod/ingress-nginx-admission-patch-6sq94         0/1     Completed   1          2d23h   10.244.0.23     master-node   <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx   pod/ingress-nginx-controller-7896b4fbd4-ccn2n   1/1     Running     0          2d23h   10.244.0.24     master-node   <none>           <none>
kube-system     pod/coredns-66bff467f8-46sgr                    1/1     Running     0          51d     10.244.0.3      master-node   <none>           <none>
kube-system     pod/coredns-66bff467f8-fnjn7                    1/1     Running     0          51d     10.244.0.2      master-node   <none>           <none>
kube-system     pod/etcd-master-node                            1/1     Running     0          51d     62.75.216.101   master-node   <none>           <none>
kube-system     pod/kube-apiserver-master-node                  1/1     Running     1          51d     62.75.216.101   master-node   <none>           <none>
kube-system     pod/kube-controller-manager-master-node         1/1     Running     23         51d     62.75.216.101   master-node   <none>           <none>
kube-system     pod/kube-proxy-7r7vk                            1/1     Running     0          51d     62.75.216.101   master-node   <none>           <none>
kube-system     pod/kube-scheduler-master-node                  1/1     Running     25         51d     62.75.216.101   master-node   <none>           <none>

NAMESPACE       NAME                                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE     SELECTOR
default         service/clientweb-service                    ClusterIP   10.103.212.174   <none>        80/TCP                       2d23h   app=clientweb
default         service/kubernetes                           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      51d     <none>
ingress-nginx   service/ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.96.161.144    <none>        80:32335/TCP,443:31481/TCP   2d23h   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
ingress-nginx   service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.98.123.43     <none>        443/TCP                      2d23h   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
kube-system     service/kube-dns                             ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       51d     k8s-app=kube-dns

NAMESPACE     NAME                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES                          SELECTOR
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy   1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   51d   kube-proxy   k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.18.6   k8s-app=kube-proxy

NAMESPACE       NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES                                                                                                                SELECTOR
default         deployment.apps/clientweb-dep              1/1     1            1           47d     clientweb    ethernial.azurecr.io/clientweb:26                                                                                     app=clientweb
default         deployment.apps/portalapi-dep              1/1     1            1           49d     portalapi    ethernial.azurecr.io/portalapi:22                                                                                     app=portalapi
ingress-nginx   deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           2d23h   controller   k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.35.0@sha256:fc4979d8b8443a831c9789b5155cded454cb7de737a8b727bc2ba0106d2eae8b   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
kube-system     deployment.apps/coredns                    2/2     2            2           51d     coredns      k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7                                                                                              k8s-app=kube-dns

NAMESPACE       NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES                                                                                                                SELECTOR
default         replicaset.apps/clientweb-dep-5b96dc777b              0         0         0       47d     clientweb    ethernial.azurecr.io/clientweb:21                                                                                     app=clientweb,pod-template-hash=5b96dc777b
default         replicaset.apps/clientweb-dep-5d58cfb88f              1         1         1       21d     clientweb    ethernial.azurecr.io/clientweb:26                                                                                     app=clientweb,pod-template-hash=5d58cfb88f
default         replicaset.apps/portalapi-dep-857dfbf98               0         0         0       49d     portalapi    ethernial.azurecr.io/portalapi:16                                                                                     app=portalapi,pod-template-hash=857dfbf98
default         replicaset.apps/portalapi-dep-c8845948b               1         1         1       23d     portalapi    ethernial.azurecr.io/portalapi:22                                                                                     app=portalapi,pod-template-hash=c8845948b
default         replicaset.apps/portalapi-dep-cdf85c5cf               0         0         0       48d     portalapi    ethernial.azurecr.io/portalapi:18                                                                                     app=portalapi,pod-template-hash=cdf85c5cf
ingress-nginx   replicaset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller-7896b4fbd4   1         1         1       2d23h   controller   k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.35.0@sha256:fc4979d8b8443a831c9789b5155cded454cb7de737a8b727bc2ba0106d2eae8b   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx,pod-template-hash=7896b4fbd4
kube-system     replicaset.apps/coredns-66bff467f8                    2         2         2       51d     coredns      k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7                                                                                              k8s-app=kube-dns,pod-template-hash=66bff467f8

NAMESPACE       NAME                                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES                                          SELECTOR
ingress-nginx   job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create   1/1           24s        2d23h   create       docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.2.2   controller-uid=5f09375f-e7a5-4625-b7d1-37298975afad
ingress-nginx   job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch    1/1           30s        2d23h   patch        docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.2.2   controller-uid=23a26ffb-f2d8-4c4c-b361-b690a39befaa
```

Comment: Are you sure your container listen on port 80? Have you set that port in your docker image? Could you add your deployment yaml? Could you try to add `targetPort: 80` in your service and check if that works?

Comment: @Jakub I have added the deployment I will try to add targetPort, on the machine there was installed apache2 but I have stopped it.

Comment: @Jakub does not work!

Comment: What about the port in your docker image? Is your ingress pod up and running?

Comment: Hi, this is my dockerfile, I can run it and view on my local machine:
FROM tiangolo/node-frontend:10 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY Ethernial.Client/package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY Ethernial.Client/ /app/
RUN npm run build
# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.15
COPY --from=build-stage /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
# Copy the default nginx.conf provided by tiangolo/node-frontend
COPY --from=build-stage /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Comment: @Jakub added kubectl get all -A -o wide

Comment: I checked [here](https://tech.amikelive.com/node-830/reactjs-changing-default-port-3000-in-create-react-app/comment-page-1/) and by default react listen on port 3000, could you try to add `EXPOSE 3000 80` to your docker file so it would listen on port 80, which is configured in your ingress, and I assume nginx?

Comment: @Jakub are you sure? the docker is using nginx not npm start

Comment: @jakub nope it is port 80
PS C:\Users\Reloa> docker run -d ethernial.azurecr.io/clientweb
d44f86578d4e8daf80fff180ff573225113c596a7d76e81b4f4f362787a6ae33
PS C:\Users\Reloa> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d44f86578d4e        ethernial.azurecr.io/clientweb   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   6 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        80/tcp              nostalgic_perlman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113605/discussion-between-raffa50-and-jakub).